# TortoiseSVN issue tracker plugin built - but not implemented

Tags: plugins, tortoisesvn, salesforce, jira

I've read all the info of how to build an issue tracker plug-in in C#  for TortoiseSVN.
I done that, building a class library with integration to my issue tracking (SalesForce).

I don't know how to install it to TortoiseSVN itself.

I've created a setup for the solution and I can install it (like JIRA solution that I found online).

I don't know what is missing.

#### Update:

I did what you wrote, made sure everything is correct.
I don't get the name of the provider, but the GUID, and an error:
[alt text http://img339.imageshack.us/img339/8558/sfsvnerror.jpg](http://img339.imageshack.us/img339/8558/sfsvnerror.jpg)

what can it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You need to make sure that you have the right CLSIDs registered in the registry - so my installer inserts the following (fake) values:

(This, I think should be the equivalent of running RegASM as detailed at the bottom of the [issue-tracker-plugins.txt](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisesvn/source/browse/trunk/contrib/issue-tracker-plugins/issue-tracker-plugins.txt) file.

[Installer Registry Changes Image http://img291.imageshack.us/img291/1618/registryinstaller.png](http://img291.imageshack.us/img291/1618/registryinstaller.png)

You **should** be able to import this registry file to get you started:

(You will probably have to dynamically update the CodeBase location, based on where the dll is installed to)

> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{AAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAA}]
>   @="FogBugzPlugin.MyPlugin"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{AAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAA}\Implemented
>   Categories]
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{AAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAA}\Implemented
>   Categories{3494FA92-B139-4730-9591-01135D5E7831}]
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{AAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAA}\Implemented
>   Categories{62C8FE65-4EBB-45E7-B440-6E39B2CDBF29}]
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{AAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAA}\InprocServer32]
>   @="mscoree.dll"
>   "ThreadingModel"="Both"
>   "Class"="FogBugzPlugin.MyPlugin"
>   "Assembly"="MyAssemblyName,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31286c9d1d5aa00a"
>   "RuntimeVersion"="v2.0.50727"
>   "CodeBase"="file:///C:/Program
>   Files/folder/AAAAAAAAAAAAA/MyAssemblyName.dll"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{AAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAA}\InprocServer32\1.0.0.0] "Class"="FogBugzPlugin.MyPlugin"
>   "Assembly"="MyAssemblyName,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31286c9d1d5aa00a"
>   "RuntimeVersion"="v2.0.50727"
>   "CodeBase"="file:///C:/Program
>   Files/folder/AAAAAAAAAAAAA/MyAssemblyName.dll"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{AAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAA}\ProgId]
>   @="FogBugzPlugin.MyPlugin"

2) You need to make sure that the user gets the BugTraq Associations added to the registry:

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\TortoiseSVN\BugTraq Associations\0]
"Provider"="{AAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAA}"
"WorkingCopy"="c:\"
"Parameters"=""

(This can also be done manually by the user by going to TSVN -> Settings -> Hook Scripts -> Issue Tracker Integration -> Add

Where "{AAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAA}" is the GUID of the provider that you created.

All being well, the plugin should now be available to the user. when they open the commit dialog.

---

Update:

Troubleshooting the "Provider Shows As GUID" Issue seen above...

OK... so assuming your provider GUID is

```
{0DA7E319-1DCE-4A94-65555B5B6CE5}
```

You should check:

Your plugin implements IBugTraqProvider and IBugTraqProvider2 and has the GUID applied to it:

```
namespace FogBugzPlugin
{
[ComVisible(true),
     Guid("0DA7E319-1DCE-4A94-65555B5B6CE5"),
     ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    public class MyPlugin : IBugTraqProvider, IBugTraqProvider2
```

So now you should have:
GUID: 0DA7E319-1DCE-4A94-65555B5B6CE5
PluginName: FogBugzPlugin.MyPlugin

Go to regedit and have a look and see what you have in the registry. It should be along the lines of:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{0DA7E319-1DCE-4A94-65555B5B6CE5}]
@="FogBugzPlugin.MyPlugin"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{0DA7E319-1DCE-4A94-65555B5B6CE5}\Implemented Categories]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{0DA7E319-1DCE-4A94-65555B5B6CE5}\Implemented Categories\{3494FA92-B139-4730-9591-01135D5E7831}]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{0DA7E319-1DCE-4A94-65555B5B6CE5}\Implemented Categories\{62C8FE65-4EBB-45E7-B440-6E39B2CDBF29}]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{0DA7E319-1DCE-4A94-65555B5B6CE5}\InprocServer32]
@="mscoree.dll"
"ThreadingModel"="Both"
"Class"="FogBugzPlugin.MyPlugin"
"Assembly"="FogBugz2Tortoise, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31286c9d1d5aa00a"
"RuntimeVersion"="v2.0.50727"
"CodeBase"="file:///C:/Program Files/folder/FogBugz2Tortoise/FogBugz2Tortoise.dll"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{0DA7E319-1DCE-4A94-65555B5B6CE5}\InprocServer32\1.0.0.0]
"Class"="FogBugzPlugin.MyPlugin"
"Assembly"="FogBugz2Tortoise, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31286c9d1d5aa00a"
"RuntimeVersion"="v2.0.50727"
"CodeBase"="file:///C:/Program Files/folder/FogBugz2Tortoise/FogBugz2Tortoise.dll"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{0DA7E319-1DCE-4A94-65555B5B6CE5}\ProgId]
@="FogBugzPlugin.MyPlugin"
```

**You should also have the ProgID / CLSID entry directly under HKCR:**

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\FogBugzPlugin.MyPlugin]
@="FogBugzPlugin.MyPlugin"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\FogBugzPlugin.MyPlugin\CLSID]
@="{0DA7E319-1DCE-4A94-65555B5B6CE5}"
```

Hope this helps - I'd check the last point first.

Comment: Does it means that I will have to manually configure for each user?

Comment: Probably - the bugtracker associations are stored in HKLU, so need to be created for each user - but this can be done in the TSVN UI, by selecting the installed provider and setting the paramaters (if any) and the working copy path.

Comment: Working perfect. Although I do have a problem in my code. Whenever I'm in the function "GetCommitMessage2", I return string, but it crashes.
Do you know why?

Comment: I'd Make sure you've implemented all of IBugTraqProvider2 - it may be down to not returning a string from OnCommitFinished or something.